# How to convert binary format to xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, binary

I am taking  a file and converting it to binary in a array like this:

```
FileStream st = new FileStream(openFile.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[st.Length];
        st.Read(buffer, 0, (int)st.Length);
        st.Close();
```

Now that I have it into binary what would be the best way to turn this into a xml file. Would I have to convert this to a string or I don't even know how I would. If this question wasnt clear please let me know I will edit it. Welcome to any suggestions PLEASE HELP, thanks again.

Comment: We don't know your data structure, how can we suggest a way to create a xml from it?

Comment: binary format of what? there are a number of xml classes which will help you there, but you need to give it a structure of some form to export a bunch of 0s and 1s will be no use to anything

Answer (score 0):

Use your buffer to create memory stream and then you can load and save XML document.

```
XmlDocument myXML = new XmlDocument();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
myXML.Load(ms);
myXML.Save(".../myfile.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

you must use Convert.ToBase64String()

```
Convert.ToBase64String(st);
```

and this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e041cec4-1570-4b5b-87fd-ecbdb56275d5/how-to-convert-binary-byte-data-into-string-and-again-from-string-to-binary-byte-array?forum=csharplanguage) maybe help you.